# What percentage of USA have a 'dangerous' STI

Tags: statistics, sti

After a quick google search I found that 1 out of 5 people in the USA are estimated to have an STD, which seems like allot!

However, the vast majority of those are HPV, and if vaccinated I don't think it is likely to cause severe issues.  So I wanted to get an estimation of what percentage of the USA have an STI that would cause an individual serious regret if they caught it.  So by dangerous STI I mean the following.

- If regular STI checkups could detect and treat the STI with no long term effect it's not 'dangerous'.
- If the effects of the STI are minimal enough to someone properly vaccinated and healthy that they are unlikely to notice it then it's not dangerous
- If it can be expected to have permanent health issues, even if not life threatening; so for example Herpes (the genital one, not cold sores), then it is dangerous.

Given that more restrictive definition is there an estimation of what percentage of the population is likely to have an STI like that.

Comment: Best to cite your sources, as well.

Comment: I think a challenging aspect of this question is to arbitrarily define "dangerous". What's one person's "health issue" may be another person's minor inconvenience. It might be better to reframe the question with a pre-existing list of STIs or define it in a way previous researchers have defined it (and provide a link).

Comment: Aside from what @IanCampbell has said, I think your definition of 'dangerous' needs work. For example, with point 1, regular STI checkups could detect HIV early, and medication can prevent it from leading to life threatening AIDS. But, no regular checks can lead to death from an HIV infection, which has led to AIDS. So, the regular checkups doesn't alter the fact that an HIV infection, or even its progression to AIDS, is dangerous if not dealt with.